# Approximation by simple functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,S,\mu)$ a $\sigma$-finite measure space. Suppose that $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable and $f\ge 0$, then there exists $s_n:X\to\mathbb{R}$ simple and measurable functions such that $0\le s_n\le s_{n+1}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $s_n(x)\to f(x)$ for every $x\in X$ and $\mu(\{x\in X:s_n(x)>0\})<+\infty$.

Of course, I know the 'usual' theorem of approximation, in any measure space without the last condition $\mu(\{x\in X:s_n(x)>0\})<+\infty$, so we should use this space is $\sigma$-finite.

Any hint?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write $X$ as a countable union of sets $X_n$ which have finite measure, and $X_n\subset X_{n+1}$. If $f_n$ is a sequence of simple functions increasing to $f$, then $f_n\cdot \chi_{X_n}$ is also a sequence of simple functions of finite measure support, increasing to $f$.

Comment: Thanks!! @DimitriosNtalampekos

Answer (score 0):

You have $X=\bigcup_kX_k$, with $X_k\subset X_{k+1}$. Define
$$
s_n(x)=\begin{cases}\displaystyle \frac{\lfloor nf(x)\rfloor}n,&\ \displaystyle x\in\bigcup_{1}^nX_k,\\ \ \\
\ \ 0,&\ \text{ otherwise }\end{cases}
$$